# Why does this code cause a stack overflow? And why just change ==1 to <2, and then it works?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Below is the code of recursive Fibonacci, and it causes a stackoverflowerror. Why does just changing the condition from n==1 to n<2 make it work?

Consider the normal Fibonacci function: F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2). That function can be represented here as F(n) = calculate(n, 2).

The concept here is that calculate(n, x) = calculate(n - 1, x) + calculate(n - 2, x) + calculate(n - 3, x) + ...+ calculate(n - x, x);

```
    public static int calculate(int n, int x) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return n;
        }
        else {
            int output = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                output += calculate(n - i, x);
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually, F(0) is zero (not 1).

Comment: "Why does just changing the condition from n==1 to n<2 make it work?" - hint: can you think of numbers that are less than 2, but are not equal to 1? Can you think of a way that `n` could be such a number? What do you think should happen in that case?

Answer (score 1):

When your stopping condition is just `n == 1`, `calculate` won't stop if you pass to it `0` or negative values, which is what you are doing in your loop.

For example, if `n == 2` and `x == 2`, `calculate(n - i, x)` becomes `calculate(0,2)` when `i == x`.

Therefore, `if (n <= 1)` or `if (n < 2)` is the correct stopping condition.